# php mysql select statement without repetition

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an application that should fetch data from mysql database to send sms. I'm decided to use cron job service to run a php script to fetch the data and send the sms after every 5 minutes.

My problem is I just can not figure out a way of setting up the select statement to NOT pick a record that had been picked earlier. That only fresh since the last run are selected and data is sent. 
Kindly, any one lead me please...

```
  //fetches fresh records
$sql = "SELECT name,amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer ";


$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1); // fetch data from db

      get the variables from array
    $name = $resultarr['name'];
    $amount = $resultarr['amount'];
    $transaction_id = $resultarr['trans_id'];
    $date = $resultarr['time_paid'];

    // message template to be sent
    $message = "Dear $name we have received $amount from you. MPESA transaction Id $transaction_id on $date.";

      // requirements to send sms
    $mobilenumber = $resultarr['msisdn']; // get mobile number from array
    $message_sent = $message;

     //passing them as service arguments
    $serviceArguments = array(
            "mobilenumber" => $mobilenumber,
            "message" => $message_sent
    );

      //webservice to send sms
    $client = new SoapClient("http://50.33.64.16:8080/smsengine/smsws?WSDL");

    $result = $client->process($serviceArguments);

    return $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible idea could be to dump all processed record in a table(say tbl2) and Next time when you going to fetch records, Select all the record from primary table that don't exist in table tbl2.

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```